# If a variable holds a certain value, then print out the value of a different variable

Tags: r

How do I go from:

```
  Method  Message             
Distance      123     
Color         Red 
Distance      545     
Color        Blue   
Distance      419
```

To:

```
  Method  Message    Value   Pick         
Distance      123      123  
Color         Red             Red
Distance      545      545
Color        Blue            Blue
Distance      419      419
```

Coming from SPSS it was a measly

```
IF  (Method  = "Distance") Value=Message. 
IF  (Method  = "Color") Pick=Message. 
EXECUTE.
```

But for R I just can't get out of the SPSS mindset. 
I tried:

```
Value <- ifelse(df$Method == "Distance", df$Message, 0)

Pick <- ifelse(df$Method == "Color", df$Message, 0)
```

No luck.

I might be stuck in an SPSS mindset. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your columns are factors. Try to convert them to character columns using `as.character` before creating the new columns:

```
transform(df, Value = ifelse(Method == "Distance", as.character(Message), ""),
              Pick = ifelse(Method == "Color", as.character(Message), ""))

#     Method Message Value Pick
# 1 Distance     123   123     
# 2    Color     Red        Red
# 3 Distance     545   545     
# 4    Color    Blue       Blue
# 5 Distance     419   419
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dummy dataframe
df <- read.table(text="Method  Message             
                 Distance      123     
                 Color         Red 
                 Distance      545     
                 Color        Blue   
                 Distance      419", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)
#Add columns
df$Value <- ifelse(df$Method=="Distance", df$Message, "")
df$Pick <- ifelse(df$Method=="Color", df$Message, "")

#Output
df
#     Method Message Value Pick
# 1 Distance     123   123     
# 2    Color     Red        Red
# 3 Distance     545   545     
# 4    Color    Blue       Blue
# 5 Distance     419   419
```

Answer (score 0):

How about with `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)
df<-data.frame(Method=rep(c("Distance","Color"),length.out=5),Message=c(123,"Red",545,"Blue",419))
df$Message<-as.character(df$Message) # convert factors to character type

ddply(df,
      .(Method,Message),
      transform,
      Value=ifelse(Method=="Distance",Message,""),
      Pick=ifelse(Method=="Color",Message,"")
      )

    Method Message Value Pick
1    Color    Blue       Blue
2    Color     Red        Red
3 Distance     123   123     
4 Distance     419   419     
5 Distance     545   545
```